# Git remote clone

Tags: git, git-svn

I've git repo on remote server. I have ssh access to this server. When I try to clone the repo with command `git clone ssh://nick@ip_addres:9022/repo.git` I can't clone it. Error that appear is 
`git clone ssh://nick@ip_address:9022/repo.git
Cloning into repo...
fatal: '/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ssh to that machine with the name login and do `cd /repo.git`, what do you get ?

You are probably missing the path to the repository...

Comment: When I type `git://ip_addres/repo.git` everything is fine.

Comment: As far as I remember the default port of `git:` is `9418`. On the other hand `git:` is an other protocol than `ssh:`, so you are sure you have a ssh-server up and running on the server and that it listens on your preferred port `9022` (default for ssh is `22`)? Try `ssh nick@ip_adress:9022`

Comment: Good so far. Now, that you are on the remote machine, read @Mattieus answer and find out where is `repo.git` there ;)

Comment: You repo must be somewhere on the remote machine, you need to locate it to be able to clone it. Once you do, copy its full path instead of `/repo.git` at the end of your command. And let us know if it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just a (legitimate ;)) guess

```
git clone ssh://nick@ip_adress:9022/~nick/repo.git
```

This is a consequence from @Matthieu answer. I dont assume, that there is really a directory `repo.git` in the root of your server. This answer expects, that the repo is in 'nick's home.